# SharePoint "Alert Me" alert deleted automatically

Tags: list, document-library, 2016, alert

We received an inquiry from sharepoint user that existing alerts are deleted automatically.
According to her, alert deleted 2 times in several months and some other members faced same issue.

Strangely, alert is not deleted to all members. Some members deleted their alert but some other members did not deleted same alert.
Is there any clue?

Thank you,